# nil checking on blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that does an asynchronous network call, and then passes the success or failure results back via blocks:

```
- (void) loginWithSuccess:(void (^)(id responseObject))success failure:(void (^)(NSError* error))failure {
...
  if(error) {
    failure(error);
  }
  else {
    success(responseObject);
  }
}
```

I noticed that if I call this method and pass in `nil` as my blocks, my application will crash with `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`:

```
[manager loginWithWithSuccess:nil failure:nil];
```

But, if I pass in empty blocks, it runs fine:

```
[manager loginWithWithSuccess:^(id responseObject){} failure:^(NSError *error){}];
```

I assume this is because at runtime you can't pass parameters to `nil`? So, when defining my methods that take blocks, should I always check that the blocks are not nil before calling them?

Comment: The library you're using should be guarding against a `nil` Block, because `doThatThingYouDoWithCompletion:aBlock error:nil` should be the way you say "I don't want to hear about errors".

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, I'll put in nil checks. Also thanks for pointing to the other answer.

Comment: @RajanBalana: Uh, no. `NULL == nil`. Neither can be called as a function. `dispatch_block_t crash = NULL; crash();`

Comment: @JoshCaswell You are right !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at Apple's Frameworks, some methods with block parameters accept `NULL/nil` as the block argument (e.g. `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`), others don't (e.g. `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`).

If you're designing an API, you have to make that decision. If it makes sense to not have a block, you should accept `nil` and check before executing the block, otherwise you should throw an assertion like `[@[] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:nil]` does:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]: block cannot be nil'
```

#### So why are you getting `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`?

When invoking a block you are dereferencing the address, which you obviously can't do if it's not pointing to an actual block. There is a great explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703717/1489997).

Comment: The important difference between the two kinds of methods being, of course, can the method still do its job without the Block?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following example to understand call block logic:

```
void (^printString)(NSString*) = ^(NSString* arg) {
    NSLog(@"%@", arg);
};

//(1) printString = ^(NSString* arg){};
//(2) printString = NULL;

printString(@"1");
```

In the console you will see "1". Then uncomment (1) and console reveals "Called" but no errors!
And at last, uncomment (2) and get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. It is your situation exactly.

Called block must be not NULL or nil. You need to check existence of passing blocks in loginWithSuccess before call.