# Preventing a crash if a block is nil without thousands of ifs

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, categories

I love using blocks. I constantly create custom classes that use blocks to communicate with callers instead of delegate mechanisms.

But the problem is that these classes got polluted with checks to see if the block was declared before running them. Something like:

```
if (self.onExit) {
  self.onExit(flag);
}
```

obviously I cannot omit the `if` or the code will crash if `_onExit` is `nil`;

Is there something I can create, a category or something, that will allow me to just run the block directly without the thousands of `if`s but will internally check for nil before running it?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider migrating to swift and use a much shorter `?` unwrapping :)

Comment: Switch to Swift. In Swift blocks are known as closures, and a closure that can be nil is enclosed in an Optional. You can resolve an optional with a question mark. So you'd say `self.onExit?()`. The question mark means "check the closure to see if it's nil. If yes, stop. If it's not nil, call it.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot migrate this code to swift because this is a project for someone else.

Comment: Why do you have thousands of `if`s for this one property? Why don't you wrap their use in a helper method? Then use the helper method and only have one `if` (inside the helper method).

Comment: @maddy - because this is called from several other viewcontrollers.

Comment: I think rmaddy's saying something like this: https://gist.github.com/woolsweater/d90584352833f6b0a8d7414479321eee

Comment: @JoshCaswell Exactly. Nice.

Comment: @SpaceDog Unrelated FYI - when you wish to reply to someone, type `@` and the first letter of their username. A tooltip of matching users currently involved in the question/comments will appear. Press tab to complete the username automatically. If no tooltip appears then the username you are trying to use is incorrect. I didn't see your last reply because my username is not `maddy`, it's `rmaddy`. Enjoy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a macro like this?

> #define BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(block, ...) block ? block(__VA_ARGS__) : nil

This is from another answer with more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13037198/747339

Answer (score 2):

[rmaddy suggested this in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322471/preventing-a-crash-if-a-block-is-nil-without-thousands-of-ifs/40347548#comment67902259_40322471) and I followed up with an example: a little bit of refactoring might be the way to go here. Put the null-check-and-call into a method. Then call the method unconditionally wherever you have the conditional call of the Block.

Something like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^onExit)(BOOL);
@end

@interface MyClass ()
- (void)performExit:(BOOL)flag;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)performExit:(BOOL)flag
{
    if( self.onExit ){
        self.onExit(flag);
    }
}

- (void)doThatThing
{
    // Replace
    // if( self.onExit ){
    //     self.onExit(flag);
    // }
    // with
    [self performExit:YES];
    // everywhere.
}

@end
```

Comment: and how do one use that?

Comment: Just call `performExit:` wherever you're currently testing and calling the Block.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how I can run a block that way according to the way I asked.

Comment: The method is calling the Block for you. I've just moved the test for `nil` inside the method so that it doesn't have to be written out every time.